# Is Oracle NOW fully supported by .NET entity framework?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I was having trouble finding a path/resource to the query if oracle is supported by Entity framework.
If it does ... which of the following Workflows does it support?

1. Model First
2. Database First
3. Code first(new database)
4. Code first (Existing database)

Kindly also mention the resource where I can  learn Entity framework that has support for oracle.